# C# Determine which of several timers has expired

Tags: c#, .net-core, timer, event-handling

I have an array of objects and each object has its own timer.  If, when constructing the arrayed objects I pass my own timer event handler for use in the timers, is there any way to tell which object's timer has expired.

If not, it seems all the objects in my array would need to catch their own timers and I'd need to implement a completely different delegate that took something like InnerObject as a parameter so the inner objects own event handler could call it like this:  OuterDelegate(this,eventArgs);

All the various ways along the same line are such a ridiculous amount of trouble I can't help but think there must be a better way.  On other systems the timer always takes a token that is included in parameters to the event handler but I can't find anything resembling that in .net (core).

Comment: Can you share a bit of the code?

Comment: I've not written any.  I'm trying to design something and I want to do it right the first time.  Imagine any array of timers where all of them call the same handler.  How does the handler know which one popped?

Comment: Examine the eventargs of the timer event. There should be something that points to the timer that raised the event

Comment: There is, but a pointer to a timer that belongs to another object doesn't tell me which object owns the timer.  At best, if all the objects expose their timers I'd still need to search through all possible objects looking for the one whose timer I have.  That's totally impractical and impossible if the timers themselves are not exposed.  Which is why I posted the question.  Needing to go through that much trouble seemed ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that System.Timers is complete junk but not your only choice.
System.Threading.Timer has exactly the features I was looking for.  I just didn't realize there were two version until I stumbled on certain complaints that clued me to the fact that they are not the same and I finally looked at the threading version.

Edit:

System.Threading.Timer's callback looks like this

```
public delegate void TimerCallback(object state);
```

Where state is an arbitrary object passed to the timer during construction.  It  can encapsulate anything the event handler needs to properly handle the specific instance of the event.   You can even set properties or call methods on the object during event handling thus controlling its state based on the timer.

Edit-2

The only thing in the System.Timers implementation that is vaguely similar is the ability to attach a System.ComponentModel.ComponentCollection and the ability to point to a Component within the collection.  These are COM objects belonging to System.​Windows.​Forms.​Control. Even if you extend the class to meet your own needs you drag support for unusable properties around with you.

You can extend the System.Threading.Timer just as easily without dragging unnecessary baggage along.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question. The main functional difference between the two is thread safety - knowing which timer fired the event should be equivalent between the two. If you have code for each that demonstrates why one timer works but the other doesnt that would be a useful answer.

Comment: @DStanley, Ndbuisi Jr did explain how it's possible to get similar functionality with the Timers version but his method shows that the class doesn't support what I needed.  If it did, I would not need to enhance it with a subclass. The Threading version doesn't require any enhancement.  I can add the data I want directly.  Without enhancement.

Comment: I read his answer that you _can_ extend it to get more functionality, but the event handler's `sender` parameter tells you what timer triggered the event out-of-the-box. In any case, it sounds like you have something that works, I was more wondering why you came to the conclusion that "System.Timers.Timer is junk" when it works practically the same way.

Comment: @DStanley I said "I have an array of objects and each object has its own timer".  So I could only tell which object's timer expired if the objects exposed their timers and I looped thru them all looking for the right one.  There do seem to be facilities for other types of objects to make THEIR private data available to the event handler but support covers only specific cases.  It is, therefore, not intended for general purpose use.  Adding 'complete' to my junk characterization has to do with the crazy way it behaves under certain circumstances.  Something too far off topic to post here.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is fairly simple. The `event handler` of the System.Timers.Timer `Elapsed` event is published with an argument called `sender`.

```
  _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

The `sender` is actually an instance of the System.Timers.Timer class that elapsed. 
So, with this you can know the timer that elapsed...

Further more, this class can be extended/Inherited, which means that you can create your own custom Timer class with has an extra property called Name, which you can use to compare and know which timer elapsed.
Example:

```
        class CustomTimer : System.Timers.Timer {
           public string TimerName { get; set; }
           //More properties as you need
            }
            //common handler for array of timers
            private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
                var elapsedTimer = sender as CustomTimer;
                if (elapsedTimer.TimerName.Equals(/*which ever*/)) {
                    //continue with logic
                }
                // continue with logic
            }
```

Comment: I didn't think of extending the class.  Yes that makes sense.  Thanks.  I'll up-vote but but since I read so many bad things about the Timers version compared to the Threading version and since I can use the Threading version natively I'm actually going to use that.

Comment: @bielawski you are developer, feel free to use the one you are comfortable with.

Comment: @bielawski can you mark the question as answered? Thanks

Comment: I get a popup saying I must wait another 20 hours.